# DataGridVIew Refresh not correct for added Checkbox in DataGridViewHeaderCell

Tags: c#, datagridview, header, datagridviewcheckboxcell

I am hoping that someone can shed some light on my issue.

My goal is to take an existing `DataGridView` with a `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` and add a `CheckBox` to its header cell.  I found some code while researching my question on StackOverflow and have incorporated it (with some changes) into my existing code.

The class below is the one I derived from the StackOverflow post/example (with some additional modifications):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AdvancesDistNCPC
{
    class DGVCheckBoxHeaderCell : DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell
    {
        public readonly CheckBox chkBox;
        ToolTip chkToolTip = new ToolTip();
        private Padding m_ButtonPadding = Padding.Empty;

        public DGVCheckBoxHeaderCell(string sCheckText, Color chkForeColor, Color chkBackColor, int chkBoxWidth = 40, string toolTipText = "")
        {
            chkBox = new CheckBox();// { BackColor = Color.Orange, Width = buttonWidth };
            m_ButtonPadding = new Padding(chkBox.Width + 2, 0, 0, 0);
            chkBox.Checked = false;
            chkBox.Text = sCheckText;
            chkBox.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            chkBox.ForeColor = chkForeColor;
            chkBox.BackColor = chkBackColor;
            if (toolTipText.Length > 0)
            {
                chkToolTip.SetToolTip(chkBox, toolTipText);
            }
            chkBox.CheckAlign = ContentAlignment.BottomCenter;
            chkBox.CheckedChanged += CheckedChanged;
        }

        public void ReplaceHeaderCell(DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell previousHeader)
        {
            if (previousHeader == null) return;
            SetStandardValues(previousHeader);
            var dgv = previousHeader.DataGridView;
            previousHeader.Dispose();
            dgv.Columns[previousHeader.OwningColumn.Index].HeaderCell = this;
        }

        private void SetStandardValues(DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell previous)
        {
            if (previous == null) return;
            this.Style = previous.Style;
            chkBox.Font = this.Style.Font ?? previous.DataGridView.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font;
            // etc.
        }

        private void CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OnClick(new DataGridViewCellEventArgs(ColumnIndex, RowIndex));
            //MessageBox.Show("You clicked me");
        }

        protected override void OnDataGridViewChanged()
        {
            if (this.DataGridView == null) return;
            this.DataGridView.Controls.Add(chkBox);
        }

        protected override void Paint(Graphics g, Rectangle clipBounds, Rectangle bounds, int rowIndex, DataGridViewElementStates elementState, object value, object formattedValue, string errorText, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advBorderStyle, DataGridViewPaintParts parts)
        {
            cellStyle.Padding = Padding.Add(m_ButtonPadding, cellStyle.Padding);
            base.Paint(g, clipBounds, bounds, rowIndex, elementState, value, formattedValue, errorText, cellStyle, advBorderStyle, parts);
            chkBox.Location = new Point(bounds.Left, bounds.Top + 2);
            chkBox.Height = bounds.Height - 4;
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                chkBox.MouseClick -= CheckedChanged;
                chkBox.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

I am instantiating this class after the `DataGridView` has been created and populated, and after I run through a loop to format the existing columns.

I am using the following routine to insert the header cell:

```
private void Add_AdvanceDist_ApproveAll_Checkbox(ref DataGridView dgvParm, string colName, string sToolTipText = "")
        {
            try
            {
                int colIndex = GetIndexForColName(dgvParm, colName);
                int firstColIdx = dgvParm.FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex;
                dgvParm.FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex = colIndex;
                var newCheckBoxHeaderCell = new DGVCheckBoxHeaderCell("Approve", Color.White, Color.Green);
                newCheckBoxHeaderCell.ReplaceHeaderCell(dgvParm.Columns[colIndex].HeaderCell);
                dgvParm.InvalidateCell(colIndex, 0);
                dgvParm.Columns[approvedCol].Width = 0;
                dgvParm.Refresh();
                dgvParm.FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex = firstColIdx;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
```

The code takes the existing `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` in question, and replaces its `HeaderCell` with the new `DGVCheckBoxHeaderCell` instance.

So far, the code appears to work (in that the `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` now contains the `DGVCheckBoxHeaderCell`).

However, something weird is going on with the refresh/painting of the `DataGridView`.  When it is scrolled horizontally, the following happens:

1. If the `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` is in view, the
   `HeaderCell` stays stationary (i.e., doesn't scroll with the
   rest of the cells), and
2. When the `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` disappears from view, then the `HeaderCell` does finally
   disappear, but when the `DataGridView` is scrolled (back in the other direction) so that the
   `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` is in view again, the HeaderCell is
   not subsequently painted.

It looks like this:

[image]

If I scroll back and forth, the effect within the `HeaderCell` is like a moving car window, within which the column headers whiz by.

Then, when I click directly on the ``HeaderCell```, it displays this:

[image]

which is the result I am expecting to happen automatically.

Obviously, this is a cell painting issue.  What I am doing wrong (or not doing at all like I should)?

Any suggestions and/or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Chris Fleetwood
blkwebman@mindspring.com

Comment: Try [Create a select all checkbox column Header in DataGridView Winforms](http://dotnetvisio.blogspot.com/2015/08/create-select-all-checkbox-column.html) instead. Modify the `Paint` method to apply the desired style.

Comment: @dr.null This actually worked for me (with a few mods for my specific scenario as you suggested).  Thanks for the link.